# scroll the div, not the whole page

Tags: html, css

I've seen similar questions on SO, but none that put it quite so simply as I want to do here.

Using CSS, I would like to carve a page into three sections: a left pane (which will have navigation links), a header bar, and a content pane with a scroll bar. I do not know in advance what the size of the window will be, so I want to use proportional sizing (e.g. "15%") as much as possible.

The point where I run into trouble is in giving the content pane a scroll bar to show its overflow (if any). I would like to be able to scroll that div by itself, without moving the header or left-side nav portions of the page.

I have seen this sort of thing done with the help of Javascript and resize event handlers, but I find it difficult to believe it can't be done with straightforward CSS...?

What I've got so far can be seen on [this jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmshoward/ta58xgkx/). As you can see, overflow in the content pane triggers a scollbar for the entire page, not for the content pane alone as I'd like. Any advice on how to fix this, especially with CSS alone, would be appreciated. Thanks!

Pasting the code blow, in case getting to jsfiddle is a problem. The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="layout-wrapper">
    <div class="left-pane"></div>
    <div class="right-pane">
        <div class="right-pane-header"></div>
        <div class="right-pane-content">
            <h4>Lo, a list:</h4>
            <ol>
                <li>A list item.</li>
                <li>A list item.</li>
                <li>A list item.</li>
                <!-- etc etc -->
            </ol>
        </div> <!-- right-pane-content -->
    </div> <!-- right-pane -->
</div> <!-- layout-wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url("http://hd-wall-papers.com/images/wallpapers/hd-website-backgrounds/hd-website-backgrounds-20.jpg");
    /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
}

.layout-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: inherit;
}

.left-pane {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffe0b0;
}

.right-pane {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: inherit;
}

.right-pane-header {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffb0b0;
}

.right-pane-content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: inherit;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: set height to the div which u want it to b scrolled.. and overflow hidden on body

Comment: But I don't know the height in advance-- I want it to be "whatever's left" below the header bar. It depends on how the user has the window sized.

Comment: use javascript for that n set dynamically

Comment: Are you firm on using table semantics here?  You could fix it by switching to display: flex; if not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand the question but if you just want to have scroll you can make it occupy 100% of the length of the html

```
.right-pane-content {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: inherit;
 overflow-y: auto;}
```